# ubuntu live cd no detected operating system mac

Tags: 12.04, partitioning, uefi, macbook-pro, refind

I have installed refind on a 2012 MBP running OSX 10.10, made free space with Disk Utility, and created a live cd of Ubuntu 13.04. When I get to the choice of where to install it, it says there is not detected os on the computer.

I went into the disk utility on Ubuntu and there was a partition for EFI (refind i guess), one for OSX, and about 90GB of free space.

Any ideas why I get this/how to resolve the issue?

**EDIT**

The same thing happens with 12.04.

Comment: Why an obsolete version (13.04) and not 14.04?

Comment: a certain bit of software i need is not supported on 14.04

Comment: And what about 12.04?

Comment: 12.04 would work, i thought to get the most recent one. is 13.04 bad?

Comment: Better 12.04 than 13.04. 12.04 (and 14.04) receives updates for 5 years, as it is [LTS](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS). 13.04, as a normal release, is only supported for 9 months.

Comment: ill give that a go and see if i get the same error

Comment: I also use os x and ubuntu on a MBP and never had any difficulties with dual boot/installation so far. Make a (at least 1GB) Swap partition and a linux partition (size is up to you) in `Disk Utitlity.app`instead of using linux  disk utility. Then follow the install instructions!